# How many columnfamilies do Cassandra supports up to create

Tags: cassandra

For some business requirements，I need to create many columnfamilies , that amount could reach more than 100,000.   But when the number of columnfamilies reach about 7000, my cassandra collapse, and I have to reboot it. So my question is,how many columnfamilies do Cassandra supports up to create ?

Answer (score 0):

C* memory consumption is directly correlated to the number of hot CFs of your schema. More hot CFs means more "sticked" memtables, more bloom filters, more key cache, more row cache, more everything. 100k is a very high number. Recommended CFs number is usually less than a few hundred if I remember correctly. After that, nothing will help you, eg adding nodes...

You should also need to turn off your swap (if not already done) because it will start to freeze everything when the system starts to swap out memory pages, so in my opinion: better a killed C* node than an unstable C* node that will bring down your whole cluster.

Comment: Thank you for you answer